# How to remove tuple from zip?

Tags: python-3.x, list

so i have a bunch of numbers i've tupled but am having difficulty remove an item from the zipped list.

so far i've tried .remove on the list but that gave me an error.

is there an easy way of doing this?

this is my current code:

```
Example data: 
QueenRowColumn: 3,3
TheComparisonQueen: 7,3

def CheckQueenPathDown(self, QueenRowColumn, TheComparisonQueen):


    row = []
    column = []

    CurrentLocation = QueenRowColumn
    #MoveLocation = TheComparisonQueen
    a = QueenRowColumn[0]
    b = QueenRowColumn[1]

    for i in range (-7,0):

        row.append(CurrentLocation[1] - i)
        column.append(a)

    Down = zip(row,column)

    #Down.remove(TheComparisonQueen)

    return Down
```

if i, for example were to remove "TheComparisonQueen" from the list of tuples, how would i do it?

Comment: Can you provide some example data for the two arguments: `QueenRowColumn` and `TheComparisonQueen`?

Comment: @RPyStats sure, the question has been updated.

Comment: Thanks, still need a little more understanding on my end. Are you saying `TheComparisonQueen` should be list declared with `TheComparisonQueen = [7,3]`? If so are you looking to remove values from `row` or `columns` that are in `TheComparisonQueen` or looking to drop values at the indexes of `[7,3]`?

Comment: Both `QueenRowColumn` and `TheComparisonQueen` are tuples. Sorry for the confusion. Yes i am looking to remove the Tuple `TheComparisonQueen` from `Down` which contains the tupled numbers from `row` and `column`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just looking to drop `TheComparisonQueen` from iterator of tuples you can return values that are not equal to `TheComparisonQueen` using a list comprehension or a generator expression.

```
# List Comprehension
Down = [(i,j) for i,j in zip(row,column) if (i,j) != TheComparisonQueen]

# Generator Expression
Down = ((i,j) for i,j in zip(row,column) if (i,j) != TheComparisonQueen)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.